# Is there any C++ support for Intel OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

Downloaded Intel OpenCL sdk and don't see cl.hpp.

Do I need to install anything additionally?

```
root@teja:/opt/intel/system_studio_2020/opencl-sdk/include/CL# ls
cl_d3d10.h                    cl_ext.h        cl_icd.h
cl_d3d11.h                    cl_ext_intel.h  cl_platform.h
cl_dx9_media_sharing.h        cl_gl_ext.h     cl_va_api_media_sharing_intel.h
cl_dx9_media_sharing_intel.h  cl_gl.h         cl_version.h
cl_egl.h                      cl.h            opencl.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the C++ wrapper [from the Khronos website](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/), it is not vendor-specific.